# Exodus & Trust Wallets at the same time. Is it possible? Please help

Tags: trust

I used my trust wallet’s 12 word on exodus wallet that I recently downloaded on my laptop and all the funds appears on both wallets now ! (In fact after Exodus wallet started to work the Trust wallet was showing *** for amount of each asset for a few minutes but then started to work same as before and showing all the coins now).
My question is can I keep and use both wallets at the same time ?
Also all my Tron coins are staked on Trust wallet but is still showing on exodus wallet as well. I am confused. Please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Your seed phrase (or mnemonic phrase, 12 word phrase, ...) is your key. That key simply provides access to the funds stored on the network. Wallets like Exodus, Trust, MyCrypto, MetaMask are non-custodial, meaning that they don't hold any funds themselves, and you have full control over your funds as long as you have your seed phrase.

When you use your seed phrase in different wallets, it will simply derive the same keys from that seed phrase, providing access to the same funds. You can use it across many different wallets and use the same addresses.